# Why the console.log can't run when blur event occur?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, blur

```js
 
function  fix(event){
    console.log("hello");        
} 
document.addEventListener("blur",fix,false);
```

```html
<table>
 <tr>
        <td>class</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="data"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
        <td>name</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="data"></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

So simple the js function.
I want `console.log` execute when blur event occur,no matter the mouse's focus go out off which input,`hello` show on console.
What's wrong with my fix function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`blur` does not bubble, so it won't be visible if you use event delegation like that - you'll only see the `blur` event if the listener for it is attached directly to the element in question. If you want to use event delegation, listen for the `focusout` event instead:

```js
function fix(event) {
  console.log("hello");
}
document.addEventListener("focusout", fix, false);
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>class</td>
    <input type="text" class="data"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>name</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="data"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The other possibility is to listen for the `blur` event in the capturing phase instead:

```js
function fix(event) {
  console.log("hello");
}
document.addEventListener("blur", fix, true);
//                                     ^^^^
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>class</td>
    <input type="text" class="data"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>name</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="data"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass `true` as your *useCapture* argument.  As noted in the [MDN Docs for Event Delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/blur#Event_delegation), using focus out may also be required.

```js
function fix(event) {
  console.log("hello");
}
document.addEventListener("blur", fix, true);
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>class</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="data"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>name</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="data"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

As posted in the [MDN Docs for General Event Info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/blur#General_info) different browsers vary in how they listen for the event:

> Note: The value of Document.activeElement varies across browsers while this event is being handled (bug 452307): IE10 sets it to the element that the focus will move to, while Firefox and Chrome often set it to the body of the document.